# How to add missing words vectors in GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin pre-trained model?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I am using gensim word2vec library in python and using pre-trained GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin model. But,

> I have words in my corpus for which i don't have word vectors and am
> getting keyError for that how do i solve this problem?

## Here is what i have tried so far,

## 1: Loading `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` per-trained model:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
print "model loaded..."
```

## 2: Build word vector for training set by using the average value of all word vectors in the tweet, then scale

```
def buildWordVector(text, size):
vec = np.zeros(size).reshape((1, size))
count = 0.
for word in text:
    try:
        vec += model[word].reshape((1, size))
        count += 1.
        #print "found! ",  word
    except KeyError:
        print "not found! ",  word #missing words
        continue
if count != 0:
    vec /= count
return vec

trained_vecs = np.concatenate([buildWordVector(z, n_dim) for z in x_train])
```

Please tell how it is possible to add new words in pre-trained Word2vec model?

Comment: Post the code for what you have tried so far. Gensim's documentation on word2vec (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) covers what you want to achieve. If you are looking for pre-trained vectors, you can get them here - https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/

Comment: I followed the same tutorial. But i think i did not completely performed each step. I just obtained the word vectors from pre-trained model. Now, i want to extend pre-traiend models with some words or sentences at top of it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2019/06/07**

as pointed out by @Oleg Melnikov and https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/#online_training__resuming, it is not possible to resume training without the vocab tree (which doesn't get saved after training with the C code is complete)

> Note that it’s not possible to resume training with models generated by the C tool, load_word2vec_format(). You can still use them for querying/similarity, but information vital for training (the vocab tree) is missing there.

---

1. Get pre-trained vectors - eg. [Google News](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing)
2. Load the model in gensim
3. Continue training the model in gensim

These commands might come in handy

```
# Loading pre-trained vectors
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.bin', binary=True)

# Training the model with list of sentences (with 4 CPU cores)
model.train(sentences, workers=4)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks i need to ask, do we need to run "model.build_vocab(sentences)"before "model.train(sentences, workers=4) "?

Comment: I am not sure if `model.build_vocab` reinitialise the word vectors or not, but while training you can provide `trim_rule` to select the vocab you want.

Comment: So is there any way to retrain the already trained model? Or what should be the workaround for missing words that are not present in Googlenews pretrained model? Please help

Comment: You have words in corpus not present in GoogleNews model? Can you give more details on proportion of such words in the corpus?

Comment: I am using Google pre-trained model for word vectors. But, for some words I am unable to get word vectors. Now, I am looking at some way to add those words. How is this possible?

Comment: Again, can you tell me how many such words are there in the corpus? Did you set `min_count` to 1 while training the model? Did you try `build_vocab` before training?

Comment: Hey, sorry for not getting your arguments clearly. I have updated the question and hope that it will clear many things for you. I am not doing any thing like `build_vocab` or `min_count`? I think i am missing that but i don't know!

Comment: "_it’s not possible to resume training with models generated by  load_word2vec_format(). You can still use them for querying/similarity, but info vital for training (the vocab tree) is missing there._" See https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/#online_training__resuming

Comment: @OlegMelnikov Thanks for pointing out. I added this information in the answer (not removing the answer in case someone else has similar issues)